# How to find a multi-day park-and-ride for Paris?

Tags: automobiles, paris

We are planning to go by car to Paris for a few (2-4) days. As I'm a bit afraid of crashing my car or having trouble parking I was thinking of leaving it somewhere outside Paris and continue by train/bus/metro.

Are these kind of park-and-rides available near Paris? Can I find somewhere a list of options, including their prices?

(I'll be approaching Paris from the north, the A1 probably)

Comment: Why not Lille? Paris is just one hour away by TGV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your budget - there are hotels that have garages. We stayed in one a couple of years ago and our car was in their garage for 4 nights we stayed for no extra charge. Then we proceeded to Normandie. It was a medium priced hotel in Montmartre. It is really fun to drive in Paris!

Comment: This is what we ended up doing. We actually went to Montreuil and parked our car in the garage of the hotel (was €10,- a night).

Answer (score 4):

The Eurotunnel website has a [great list of park & rides](http://www.eurotunnel.com/uk/inspiration/ideas/Park-and-ride-Paris/).

Coming from the north, I'd suggest Stade de France - porte de Paris, this is just near the A1 and well-connected to Paris via RER B & D and métro line 13 (prefer using RER since the line 13 is notoriously crowded).

Another option is La Courneuve - 8 mai 1945. You'll be at the noth end of the métro line 7 (pink one), this line will get you to the Louvre in ~20 min.